# Get the --bin argument in build.rs

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'd like to handle each binary differently in `build.rs`.

I can use `env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION")` to get the version info from `Cargo.toml`.
Is there something similar for getting the bin argument?

I'd like to get `binary_name` when running `cargo run --bin binary_name`.

Comment: could you use feature flags instead? it might be more appropriate. you'd inform them with `--features a,b,c`.

Comment: That is exactly what I'd like to avoid! I want the build script to set the features based on the binary so I don't have to remember which should have what.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?